# Adding value to JS array

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have a basic question that I'm not sure how to search on a solution as I'm not exactly sure what term to search on. Sorry if this is 101 stuff.

I have a javascript object I'm trying to add values to, and not sure how. If I have the following, how to I add a record?

```
var context = {
    people: [
        {firstName: 'Homer', lastName: 'Simpson'},
        {firstName: 'Peter', lastName: 'Griffin'},
        {firstName: 'Eric', lastName: 'Cartman'},
        {firstName: 'Kenny', lastName: 'McCormick'},
        {firstName: 'Bart', lastName: 'Simpson'}
    ]
};
```

How do I add another value to "people"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use the `array.push` method:

```
context.people.push({
    firstName: 'Example',
    lastName: 'Person'
});
```

That will put it in the last slot of the array (expanded to fit the new element, of course).

Comment: Thank you! Can you recommend what term I should have searched on?

Comment: @SteveV what do you mean? What you should have searched for to find `array.prototype.push`?